# Hard Brick Lenovo s898t+

Tags: unbricking, lenovo

I have a Lenovo s898t+ Golden Warrior, I was having problems trying to update it (the update was downloaded but not installing), so, I decided to install a stock rom from: http://www.needrom.com/download/lenovo-s898t/.

I followed the steps but the phone won't boot up, keeps restarting on a black screen, I didn't make any kind of backup.

¿What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I didn't download the correct ROM, I had to download one from https://boycracked.com/2015/06/12/lenovo-s898t-stock-rom-2/, vibeui_v2.0_1503_7.18.1_st_s898t+.zip.

I hope this can help anyone with the same problem.